# Decrease time to get resultset from postgresql requests

Tags: database, postgresql

I’ve been working on a db in PostgreSQL.
My db likes **in example** :

Album :

- Id : Long
- Title : String
- Group : String

Release :

- Id : Long
- Album_id : Long
- Genre : String
- Release_date : Timestamp

Track :

- Id : Long
- Album_id : Long
- Title : String
- Duration : Long

I have nearly 11 millions entries in my Album table.
But when I do a select to make some statistics like

```
SELECT * FROM Album a 
  INNER JOIN Release r on a.Id = r.Album_id
WHERE a.Group = 'The Beatles'
```

It takes a world to gives me the resultset. I set index, and created a view to make it faster. So now, I decrease the time to nearly 15-20 seconds.

I set index, and created a view to make it faster. So now, I decrease the time to nearly 15-20 seconds.

But is there any way to make it faster?